# LilyPond: Display different time signature

Tags: lilypond, engraving

I'm engraving some early music, and, occasionally, to follow what is in the sources, I'd like to replace the symbol for what would be notated in modern time signatures as "3/2" or "4/2" with either those for common or cut time (which did not have exactly the same implications as they have now). So, for example, replace:[image: Music example in 4/2]

with something like this (without having to cheat with it in Paint, which works well for putting up an example but not quite so well for actual pieces of music...):[image: Music example in 4/2 notated as "C"]

[This](https://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=725) seems close to what I want, but I don't need the double signature, and I can't find the reference in the documentation for the C and cut C glyphs.

Comment: Is it actual mensural notation? It might be nice use the actual symbol instead of modern common/cut-time symbols, to avoid confusion.

Comment: No, it isn't, otherwise the question would not have been necessary, as in that case I think https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/typesetting-mensural-music and the linked snippet cover the issue plainly enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The glyphs are hardwired to particular number combinations, but you can use any glyph by setting `timeSignatureFraction`:

```
\set Staff.timeSignatureFraction = #'(2 . 2)  % 2/2 glyph
\time 4/2  % actually 4/2 time
```

The common and cut time glyphs aren't appropriate for 3/2. I'd either use a centered 3 (which I've seen in many early music editions):

```
\once \override Staff.TimeSignature.style = #'single-digit
\time 3/2
```

or the [mensural or neomensural glyphs](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/typesetting-mensural-music#mensural-time-signatures):

```
\override Staff.TimeSignature.style = #'mensural
\time 3/2  % circle
```

which can also be selected by setting `timeSignatureFraction` if necessary.

Comment: Minor quibble: "The common and cut time glyphs aren't appropriate for 3/2" - admittedly, by modern standards, yes, although that wasn't really part of the question. While at it, since I'm talking about "follow[ing] what is in the sources"; such notation does appear occasionally, for ex. the final (Psalm 150) of the tunes in the Becker Psalter, op. 5, by Schütz, has both a '3' and a cut-time symbol (in the original edition, available on IMSLP, p. 603).

Comment: @AlexJ Okay, I see the problem (12/1 compound meter). I don't know how to notate it, but the snippet you linked from the question plus what's in this answer should cover all reasonable options.